# Review Queue UI concern

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When reviewing things in the queue (late answers, low  quality, etc). Clicking an answer brings me to a screen that shows the the answer but the question shown under it but grayed out.

My question is wouldn't it be easier to be able to see the whole thing with the new answer focused on at first?

I ask because I have a hard time viewing if an answer was accepted or not unless I open it in a new tab or click it to view the whole thing then click back in my browser to go back to the queue.

Was something like this implemented in the past? If so why did it become the way it is now? It seems slightly counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Except the graying out, I believe the behaviour that you want is already there. Just took a quick look at Low Quality Posts queue, the other answer is below the greyed out question with votes and accepted mark. Or did I misunderstand your question? The only thing when I need to open in a new tab is when I need to flag it for other problem.

Comment: Well for some reason when I look at the queue what I see is the answer in the queue. Then below it grayed out is the question and comments for the question. No answers ever show up even if the question has accepted answers. I have to open the question in a new tab to see if the answer is accepted or not.

Comment: Ah, I just realized I'm using userscript that modifies a lot of SE features. Perhaps that's why I can see other answers directly. Sorry for the confusion, really apologize.

Comment: @AkiTanaka wish I knew how to run an SE script *pouts in corner*